# shared_ptr problems returning an up-cast version from a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, this, shared-ptr

I've recently been trying out shared_ptr and I've run across a bit of a weird case.  What I want is a template member function which is capable of returning a shared_ptr of its derived type.  I'm running visual studio 2010 which has access to some of the new c++0x standard, but I assume the boost shared_ptr behaves similarly.

This worked fine with bare pointers.  I just returned a dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(this).  I'm kind of stumped here, however, because even using enable_shared_from_this the object attempts to delete itself after the function is called (which is bad).  I am probably approaching this wrong, but I'd like to work out how to simulate the bare pointer equivalent (which was working) of the following (this is the code I'm having trouble with).

```
//assume we have a virtual function as well.
class BaseClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<BaseClass>
{
  ....
  template<typename DerivedClass>
  std::shared_ptr<DerivedClass> BaseClass::getThis(){
     //I had some assert code here to ensure typeid matched
     return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedClass>(shared_from_this());
  }
}
```

**edit**: It seems the function works correctly, the problem was with how I was using it.  It is bad, for example to do the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<DerivedClass> p = std::make_shared<DerivedClass>();
p->getType<DerivedClass>->someOtherFunctionOnlyInTheDerivedClass();
```

This is not a problem:

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> p = std::make_shared<DerivedClass>();
p->getType<DerivedClass>->someOtherFunctionOnlyInTheDerivedClass();
```

I'm not entirely sure if it's a problem with converting to the same type, or a reference counting issue.  In any case, I was doing something dumb and it broke, avoiding the unnecessary getType call at that point seems to work fine in every other case I am using it.  Maybe someone can explain precisely what causes the first example to break with the second example working.  I'll assign points to that answer.

Comment: This might have to do with the code at the place of call, show how the actual instance is created, where it is held and where is the call to the `getThis()` template performed.

Comment: are you assigning returned value after calling  getThis??????

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect a revelation.  I no longer have problems and everything seems to work correctly, but I'm curious as to what precisely broke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on Stuart's answer and to (possibly) explain why you were crashing, my best guess is that you were calling `getType` on a stack-alloc'd instance. It's a major pitfall to using `enable_shared_from_this`.

```
#include <memory>

class Base : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template <typename D>
    std::shared_ptr<D> getType()
    {
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<D>(shared_from_this());
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    d->getType<Derived>()->f(); // fine

    Derived d2;
    Base* p = &d2;
    p->getType<Derived()>->f(); // will attempt to delete d2 after f() returns.

    return 0;
}
```

The reason this occurs is because the reference count of `d2` is zero when it's on the stack. Calling `shared_from_this` returns a `shared_ptr` that increments the reference count to one. Once this pointer goes out of scope, it decrements its count to zero, which then attempts to delete the instance, which, of course, is on the stack.

The only way that I can think of protecting yourself from this, off the top of my head, is to make all constructors protected or private and provide static functions that dynamically allocate any instances, returning `shared_ptr`s, of course.

Comment: Re-assigned the correct answer because I suspect this is what happened.  Somehow there must have been a temporary object in there.  I only intend to have shared pointers to this type of object anyway so it would be a beneficial thing to hide the constructors.

Comment: I've actually run into this problem before. It took a very long while to track down the source. Happy to share my misadventures.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I don't experience the problem you're describing with the following minimal compileable example (which looks like the code you describe above):

```
#include <memory>

class Base : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Base>
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template <typename D>
    std::shared_ptr<D> getType()
    {
        return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<D>(shared_from_this());
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    d->getType<Derived>()->f();
    return 0;
}
```

Does this crash for you?

Comment: I've tested Stuart's code using clang/libc++ (-std=c++0x) and it seems to work there as well.  I added a print statement to Derived::f() as a sanity check.

Comment: Weird, this morning I've tested your minimal example (which I admit I did not compose one last night, it was getting late... Which is usually a bad time to post questions.)  No crash.  But even further, I have changed my real in-code example and am no longer seeing a crash.  I have no idea what was going on, it looks like I wrote the function correctly to begin with, maybe I was having problems with my build somehow, or possibly I am re-creating it wrong (though I'm not sure how that can be, I had it narrowed down).

Comment: Because I can't repro this today and you've taken time out of your day to hunt a goose I'm awarding you the answer.

Comment: @M2tM: Thanks :) Glad it seems to be working for you now anyway!